# Errors in latexmk with use of auto-pst-pdf and hyperref

Tags: latexmk

If we compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pstricks,auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Curves}
\begin{postscript}
\begin{pspicture}
\psccurve[showpoints=true](1,1)(2,2)(2,1)(1,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{postscript}
\end{document}
```

using `latexmk` via `pdflatex -shell-escape`, `latexmk` gives the following message.

```
Rule 'pdflatex': Rules & subrules not known to be previously run:
   pdflatex
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  -recorder  "a.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
...
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.29  <2012/06/04> (tvz)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./a.w18)) 
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2012.08.20:0705' -> a-autopp.ps
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-tools.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
PDFCROP 1.33, 2012/02/01 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `a-pics.pdf'.
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
 (/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-pdf/pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty))) (./a.aux)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
<a-pics.pdf, id=5, page=1, 43.16125pt x 33.12375pt> <use a-pics.pdf, page 1>
[1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map} <./a-pics.pdf>] (./a.aux)

Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `a.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

 )</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb
></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 18591 bytes).
SyncTeX written on a.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on a.log.
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'a.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'a.aux'
      'a.out'
------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  -recorder  "a.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
...
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.29  <2012/06/04> (tvz)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./a.w18)) 
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2012.08.20:0705' -> a-autopp.ps
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-tools.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
PDFCROP 1.33, 2012/02/01 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `a-pics.pdf'.
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
 (/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-pdf/pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty))) (./a.aux)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./a.out) (./a.out)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
(./a.toc) <a-pics.pdf, id=10, page=1, 43.16125pt x 33.12375pt>
<use a-pics.pdf, page 1> [1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map} <./a-pics.pdf>] (./a.aux) )</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 28614 bytes).
SyncTeX written on a.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on a.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'a.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'a-pics.pdf'
      'a.toc'
------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  -recorder  "a.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
...
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.29  <2012/06/04> (tvz)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./a.w18)) 
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2012.08.20:0705' -> a-autopp.ps
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-tools.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
PDFCROP 1.33, 2012/02/01 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `a-pics.pdf'.
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
 (/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-pdf/pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty))) (./a.aux)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./a.out) (./a.out)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
(./a.toc) <a-pics.pdf, id=10, page=1, 43.16125pt x 33.12375pt>
<use a-pics.pdf, page 1> [1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map} <./a-pics.pdf>] (./a.aux) )</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 28617 bytes).
SyncTeX written on a.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on a.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'a.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'a-pics.pdf'
------------
Run number 4 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  -recorder  "a.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
...
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.29  <2012/06/04> (tvz)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./a.w18)) 
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2012.08.20:0705' -> a-autopp.ps
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-tools.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
PDFCROP 1.33, 2012/02/01 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `a-pics.pdf'.
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
 (/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-pdf/pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty))) (./a.aux)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./a.out) (./a.out)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
(./a.toc) <a-pics.pdf, id=10, page=1, 43.16125pt x 33.12375pt>
<use a-pics.pdf, page 1> [1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map} <./a-pics.pdf>] (./a.aux) )</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 28619 bytes).
SyncTeX written on a.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on a.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'a.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'a-pics.pdf'
------------
Run number 5 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  -recorder  "a.tex"'
------------
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
...
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver: hpdftex.

(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
`PSTricks' v2.29  <2012/06/04> (tvz)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auto-pst-pdf/auto-pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./a.w18)) 
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: Auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
entering extended mode
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2012.08.20:0705' -> a-autopp.ps
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-tools.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>. [1] 
PDFCROP 1.33, 2012/02/01 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
==> 1 page written on `a-pics.pdf'.
-------------------------------------------------
auto-pst-pdf: End auxiliary LaTeX compilation
-------------------------------------------------
 (/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-pdf/pst-pdf.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg)))
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty))) (./a.aux)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./a.out) (./a.out)
(/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
(./a.toc) <a-pics.pdf, id=10, page=1, 43.16125pt x 33.12375pt>
<use a-pics.pdf, page 1> [1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{/home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map} <./a-pics.pdf>] (./a.aux) )</home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></home/jasperloy/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on a.pdf (1 page, 28613 bytes).
SyncTeX written on a.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on a.log.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'a.pdf'
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'a-pics.pdf'
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
     Use the -f option to force complete processing.
Latexmk: Did not finish processing file:
   'pdflatex' needed too many passes
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
```

Note the output has been truncated to fit maximum question length.

I suspect this is because `hyperref` makes `latexmk` do extra checks, which then detects that new pictures are generated by `auto-pst-pdf` with each run, so although the end result may be right, the error messages are given. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: what happens if you load `hyperref` last?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason `latexmk` keeps re-running is because the generated `a-pics.pdf` file keeps changing on every run. There are lines in the PDF file with creation dates, modification dates and IDs that keep changing. There are at least two possible solutions.

1. Tell `latexmk` to ignore `a-pics.pdf` completely from its dependency
   database. There does not currently seem to be an interface exposed to do this (and [modifying the recorder file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294689/17427) does not work in this instance), so I do it with the following hack, which redefines an internal function used by `latexmk` to maintain its file database. Put the following in a `latexmkrc` file, in the same directory as your main `tex` file (and be aware that this will affect all other `latexmk` runs started from the same directory):

   ```
   undef &get_time_size;

   sub my_get_time_size {
      # Return time and size of file named in argument
      # If file does not exist, return (0,-1);
      if ( -e $_[0] && $_[0] ne $root_filename . "-pics.pdf") {
          return get_time_size_raw($_[0]);
      }
      else {
          return (0,-1);
      }
   }

   *get_time_size = \&my_get_time_size;
   ```
2. Tell `latexmk` not to
   consider changes to the creation date etc to indicate that the file
   itself has changed. This you can do as follows: get `latexmk` to
   execute the perl code `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} =
   '^/(CreationDate|ModDate|ID) ';`. For example, on the command line
   for your example:

   ```
   latexmk -e "\$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^/(CreationDate|ModDate|ID) ';" -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex --shell-escape  %O  %S" a
   ```

   (where `a` is the name of your job).

   Alternatively, you could add the contents of the `-e` argument to a `latexmkrc` resource file, changing the escaping appropriately.

   Note that method 2 will result in one unnecessary re-run, but at least it should no longer cause an infinite loop!
3. A possible third solution might be to [disable metadata generation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225790/17427), but this is probably less satisfactory than the above two approaches.

Comment: I just cannot get this to work. My main-pics.pdf is repeatedly found as modified.

Comment: @basseur: Please try approach one in my newly updated answer. Otherwise, in approach two, did the example at least work? If so, then there must be something special about your situation, which would require more details to be able to investigate.

Comment: Well, I was able to run the code, but like I said it was labeled as modified. I know that my `latexmkrc` was read because I got error messages when I deliberately left out one of the quotation marks. What has worked for me was to exclude all pdf files using `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^';`, but I am not sure about the drawbacks. However, your method seems to work perfectly and I actually understand the code. So thanks a lot!