# lualatex: how to produce PDF acceptable by arxiv?

Tags: luatex

With `pdflatex`, it is possible to create PDF files that are acceptable by `arxiv` even without sources (with `hyperref` + `\pdfsuppressptexinfo=1`, see [Making an anonymous PDF file using PDFLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95080/making-an-anonymous-pdf-file-using-pdflatex)).

However, I don't manage to create such a PDF using lualatex.

With LuaLaTeX, what is the equivalent of `\pdfsuppressptexinfo=1`?

Comment: "With LuaLaTeX, how to produce PDF acceptable by arxiv even without the sources?" - Pardon?

Comment: See also wrap-up at http://www.monperrus.net/martin/how-to-use-lualatex-arxiv

Comment: Please put that information here; you can answer your own questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The (extended) equivalent to 
`\pdfsuppressptexinfo` is `\pdfvariable suppressoptionalinfo \numexpr number\relax` see the luatex documentation. So something like this works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfcreator = {},
  pdfproducer = {}
}
\pdfvariable suppressoptionalinfo \numexpr 1+2+4+8+16+32+64+128+256+512 \relax


\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: No need for `hyperref`: `\pdfextension info {/Creator() /Producer()}`

Comment: This answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

## Message them

**Instead of working against the system, work with it**. You have a valid submission but due to technical reasons, the system ("their") fails to succesfully submit it. That's it.

LuaLatex (and friends) is not less valid than Word, LibreOffice etc.

I submitted as PDF, failed, wrote them, they flagged the submission as "non-LaTex", done. Therefore, my LaTex PDF "became" acceptable by arxiv.

Additional bonus: they learn about this and may rather accomodate LuaLatex (& friends) in the future; knowing that a feature is needed is a large motivation for devs ;)