# Making pdf file from latex anonymous

Tags: pdftex, pdf, privacy

I am trying to submit a paper to arxiv but I am giving up after trying to figure out the errors produced when my tex file is compiled by arxiv. My file compiles well with texmaker on my ubuntu machine.

I tried searching around and found this link: [click here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95080/making-an-anonymous-pdf-file-using-pdflatex/95109) where there are answers about how to make the pdf file anonymous. I tried many but none worked. Perhaps someone can shed some light.

1) I tried the pdfprivacy which supposedly automatically does this for you. After installing it, texMaker is complaining about stuff in pdfprivacy.sty.

2) I tried ps2pdf conversion. The problem is that the converted file has an extra page at the beginning with 1,-1 printed on it. It also has a page number (namely, 1) and so I simply can't cut this page out.

3) I tried adding 
\pdftrailerid{} %Remove ID
\pdfsuppressptexinfo15 
in my preamble but once again, texmaker is complaining undefined control sequence.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Wihtout more into it will be difficlut to help you.  For instance, it would be helpful if you provided the actual errors that are reported. Better still, provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem (ie, works in TexMaker for you). Also, can you elaborate what made you think that errors from compilation had to do with making the pdf annonymous.

Comment: Hi Peter, my latex file without all the other additions to make the pdf file anonymous compiles without errors. It's only when I add those commands above. For example, for 3), with \pdftrailerid, latex only says undefined control sequence. I dont think this has anything to do with packages that produce the problem

Comment: There are two parts to your question 1) how to submit latex generated pdf  to arxiv which is covered here https://www.monperrus.net/martin/how-to-use-lualatex-arxiv & additional clues for hiding a pdfLaTeX generated file.~~~ 2) In general how to strip identification from pdf. This is more problematic since a pdf is usually full of coded streams and not always obvious what embedded data can be used to identify the author / system. For 100% cleaning of pdf I use windows tools but for Linux you should consider  https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam

Comment: Thanks KJO! Regarding the first link, it says it's for luatex. Is that still applicable for me? I have seen this website before btw

Comment: Think it was mentioned in 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372154/lualatex-how-to-produce-pdf-acceptable-by-arxiv but the info in both has tips that may help with clearing object that arxiv finds in other formats. Personally I would simply reprint from a windows system virtual pdf  printer so it LOOKS like it came from say word (got a mate that can open your pdf and reprint to pdf?)

Comment: @KJO I can do it on a Windows machine if needed. What program do you recommend for reprinting a pdf?

Comment: There were several highly recommended via those articles and I use some that have oddly been withdrawn over time :-? (just my conspiracy theory) but one that is useful and I think is partially cross platform is pdftk (windows and mac installers plus source code) see this example of strip meta data from context https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/stripping-metadata-from-pdf-files/ the link is broken and the code has not been updated since 2013 but windows version works reasonably well on latest win 10 to see version history goto https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/

Comment: Here is the pdftk Linux page for pdftk https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/install-pdftk-on-redhat-or-centos/ and One of the **best very simple** tools for meta edit on windows (can also fix bad/corrupt pdf data) was https://web.archive.org/web/20180929111456/http://www.becyhome.de/becypdfmetaedit/description_eng.htm