# Submitting a XeLaTeX compiled paper to arXiv

Tags: xetex, overleaf, arxiv

I have written a paper in ***Overleaf***, compiled by ***XeLaTeX***. Now I'd like to upload it to ***arXiv***, however it seems that I have to give up on ***XeLaTeX*** for this purpose:

From ***arXiv***:

> Your submission to the archive must be in one of the following formats
>   (listed in order of preference): (La)TeX, AMS(La)TeX, PDFLaTeX

Switching to other compilers in ***Overleaf*** yields some errors of which I am not sure how to get rid of.

Do I really have to pick another compiler rather than ***XeLaTeX***, or there is a way to upload the XeLaTeX compilation of my paper to ***arXiv***?

Comment: If you paper is compilable also with LuaTeX, you can probably use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372195/82917. I don't know whether that solution would work for XeLaTeX directly.

Comment: Hello, Tom from the Overleaf Support Team here. ArXiv is in general accepting only PDFLaTeX papers. So while it is possible for us to switch your project to use older version of TeXLive, this need not help. It seems that you are using some features of LaTeX that are not compatible with XeLaTeX (mostly it's font-related stuff, and in this case, the error messages from the compiler should be helpful). Also, when you switch the project from XeLaTeX to PDFLaTeX, it's good to clear the cache. Feel free to get in touch with be on the support line, I can look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT: Solved***: Complied the paper with PDFLaTeX (had to comment out couple of  packages).

The problem was that Overleaf uses TeX Live 2018 while arXiv uses TeX Live 2016.

I have contact OverLeaf (Menu -> contact Us), and asked help, They complie my paper using TeX Live 2017.

> At the time of writing (November 2019) the arXiv service uses TeX Live 2016 to process LaTeX submissions, whereas new Overleaf projects (either created from scratch or when you clone a project) are now based on TeX Live 2018. Users wishing to submit an Overleaf project to arXiv can be affected by this mismatch in TeX Live versions due to unavoidable differences in .bbl files that arise from Overleaf running the newer BibLaTeX 3.12 and Biber 2.12 compared to arXiv’s use of BibLaTeX 3.7 and Biber 2.7. Note that Overleaf projects using BibTeX are unaffected.
>
> To address this issue, Overleaf users wishing to submit their work to arXiv should either switch to using BibTeX, or contact us and we will revert their project back to using TeX Live 2017, which includes BibLaTeX and Biber versions that are compatible with arXiv's TeX Live 2016.