# How to tweak pdftex so that it does not generate pdf metadata?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, unicode, viewers, metadata

Due to latex using fonts with character codes different than that of UTF-8 as well as a small fraction of people not using UTF-8, in some workflows, the file name of the pdf and/or the title/creator of the metadata of the pdf can contain control characters and/or other unusual symbols if they are assumed to be UTF-8. This sometimes has adverse effects on old devices and outdated software that are bad at dealing with other encodings.

How can I modify the compiler or pass command line parameters so that it does not add any metadata to the pdf and sets the filename to something generic such as `output.pdf` regardless of the name of the original `.tex` file?

Comment: latex font encodings have nothing to do with pdf metadata. Better show a small real example of your problem.

Comment: There are various ways to do this using LaTeX, but they usually involve modifying the source file, while I understand you want to do this from the command line without changing the source. For this the easiest is probably to compile normally and then post-process to remove the metadata. For example QPDF can copy all pages of a pdf into an empty target file without metadata, like `qpdf --empty --pages infile.pdf 1-z -- outfile.pdf` (see https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-selection).

Comment: For the (pdf)LaTeX approach see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95080/making-an-anonymous-pdf-file-using-pdflatex.