# latexmk ignore embedded file

Tags: latexmk

I have a TeX file with an embedded file from the command `\embedfile{\jobname.org}`. I'd like to stop `latexmk` from running when the embedded file changes. There is no official option for `latexmk` to ignore certain files, but it seems like in my specific use case it might be possible with the `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern` option.

I've added each of the following (one at a time) to my `~/.latexmkrc`:

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '^\\embedfile{\\jobname.org}';
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = 'jobname.org';
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'} = '.*jobname.org.*';
```

However, any time I change the `.org` file, `latexmk` still runs. Does anyone have any advice how to get this functionality working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two solutions, depending on your needs.

Setting the value of `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'pdf'}` is not what you want, because that instructs `latexmk` to ignore certain lines in `.pdf` files.  Instead you can instruct `latexmk` to ignore all lines in `.org` files by

```
$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'org'} = '^';
```

That will apply to all files with extension `.org`, not just to `\jobname.org`.

An alternative is to arrange that on each run of `pdflatex` the symptoms of the use of the embedded file are removed from the `.fls` file generated by `pdflatex`.  The following in a latexmkrc file worked for me:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex %O %S && ".
"perl -i -p -e \"s[^INPUT (\./|)\"%R\"\\.org\\s*\$][];\" %Y%R.fls";
```

(I've split the definition across two lines to make copying and pasting safe.  There's some UNIX-specific magic to ensure quoting works properly on the command line that is passed to the system.)

Comment: The `latexmk` command is run on a `.tex` file exported from Org that includes the `.org` source. So the `hash_calc_ignore_pattern` should be `{'tex'}`. Then I just ignore the `embed` line. Would this work? Or is this also impacted by the bug.

Comment: @mankoff No it wouldn't work, and this has nothing to do with the bug.  `Latexmk` determines the names of the source files from the `.fls` (and also `.log`) file. It then tracks these files for detecting changes in them.  Setting `$hash_calc_ignore_pattern{'tex']` as you propose wouldn't change anything about preventing changes in the `.org` file from causing a rerun of `pdflatex`.  The second solution in my answer solves your problem, as far as I understand it from your question. If it doesn't solve your problem, then your problem is different from the one you stated.

Comment: I think I stated it correctly. Your 2nd solution works for an MWE TeX or Org file. For some reason on my actual massive Org file w/ lots of LaTeX packages, it does not work. My `mgz.fls` contains `mgz.org` 3x as `INPUT ./mgz.org` and 1x as `INPUT mgz.org`. I'll wait for the next release of latexmk.